# CC PHP --> Mysql Aborted connection to db: error message

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to connect an mysql database with PDO in PHP. All on a self builded arm system.

If i query my sql in php:

```
$sql="SELECT  volume FROM measurements ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;";
```

works all fine, but if i add an additional item, like:

```
$sql="SELECT  volume , temp , humidity  FROM measurements ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;";
```

get i a blank page.

- PHP Log show no error
- activate additional error messages in php --> same
- webserver lighttpd, would not bring any error message

My Mysql server bring this errormessage, every time if i try to open my webpage:
2015-03-31T22:09:09.886345Z 26 [Note] Aborted connection XXX to db: 'database' user: 'user' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)

If i look for netstat -a | grep mysql
they show me many open connection from mysql like:

> tcp        0      0 localhost:49050         localhost:mysql   TIME_WAIT

this is my minimal php code:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=fair_database", "root", "12345");
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql="SELECT  volume , temp , humidity, co2, pressure  FROM measurements ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;";

    foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
        $first_volume = number_format ( $row['volume'],1);
        $first_temp = number_format ( $row['temp'],1);
        $first_humidity = number_format ( $row['humidity'],1);
        $first_co2 = number_format ( $row['co2'],1);
        $first_pressure = number_format ( $row['pressure'],0);
    }
      $conn=null;
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }  
?>
```

and for additional debugging i add this:

```
<?php

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// - Display Errors
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
ini_set('html_errors', 0);

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// - Error Reporting
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
error_reporting(-1);

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// - Shutdown Handler
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function ShutdownHandler()
{
    if(@is_array($error = @error_get_last()))
    {
        return(@call_user_func_array('ErrorHandler', $error));
    };

    return(TRUE);
};

register_shutdown_function('ShutdownHandler');

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// - Error Handler
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function ErrorHandler($type, $message, $file, $line)
{
    $_ERRORS = Array(
        0x0001 => 'E_ERROR',
        0x0002 => 'E_WARNING',
        0x0004 => 'E_PARSE',
        0x0008 => 'E_NOTICE',
        0x0010 => 'E_CORE_ERROR',
        0x0020 => 'E_CORE_WARNING',
        0x0040 => 'E_COMPILE_ERROR',
        0x0080 => 'E_COMPILE_WARNING',
        0x0100 => 'E_USER_ERROR',
        0x0200 => 'E_USER_WARNING',
        0x0400 => 'E_USER_NOTICE',
        0x0800 => 'E_STRICT',
        0x1000 => 'E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR',
        0x2000 => 'E_DEPRECATED',
        0x4000 => 'E_USER_DEPRECATED'
    );

    if(!@is_string($name = @array_search($type, @array_flip($_ERRORS))))
    {
        $name = 'E_UNKNOWN';
    };

    return(print(@sprintf("%s Error in file \xBB%s\xAB at line %d: %s\n", $name, @basename($file), $line, $message)));
};

$old_error_handler = set_error_handler("ErrorHandler");

// other php code
?>
```

The result is the same, only a blank page and no php errors. Other errors would be log fine in an php error logfile. :-(

I have try to enlarge the maximal package and wait time from mysql, but nothing help.
What can i do in this case? Thank you

edit: found many failures, what i change to find my problem

Comment: what you expect from this code to show if it worked correctly?

Comment: I would like to query my database with pdo(msqli are not supportet) and get the last value from volume, temp, humidity, co2 and pressure. Save this in variable and later echo to my website.

In Mysql console, work my query fine:

mysql> SELECT  volume , temp , humidity  FROM measurements ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;

+--------+------+----------+

| volume | temp | humidity |
+--------+------+----------+
|  59.76 | 1.88 |     13.7 |
+--------+------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: @MarkusF., from your example, you ask for `$first_co2 = number_format ( $row['co2'],1);`, but you have not declare the 'co2' in your select query.

Comment: yes thats right, the next silly think, which i not changed back, after trouble search.

but the problem is still the same. which only one parameter, all works fine and with more then one, they show me only a blank side(500 - Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 0):

Does your application run on Linux? This can happen if your application create and close connections more frequently. TCP connection require several steps to close a connection and if your application dies before closing the connection, the server which run MySql waits for some time for necessary TCP handshakes.

You may try with increasing MySql max_connections winch increase more room for connections. If the issue is still exists please try to adjust following kernal parameters in /etc/sysctl.conf

```
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 30
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 1
```

Meanwhile please check whether the application handles connections properly.

Comment: Thank you for an answer. Yes my php aplication run on an linux system. Php should query the database every second(only for one client, no other clients planned). I have increased the maximal connections and restart my system. After the restart the website get loading and loading over 5 minute.

after changing the ipv4 settings in /etc/sysctl.conf. My system refuse every http reqest (ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED)

Comment: Can you get the detailed error message? If you run "show processlist" on mysql prompt does the number of connections shows there has huge different with max_connections that you have configured? does the result of following command is somewhat equal to number of mysql connection that you have configured? "netstat -nt | grep TIME_WAIT | grep 3306 | wc -l"

Comment: after changing net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 30 and net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 1 in /etc/sysctl.conf . I recieve everytime if i try to open an website(Php or html) an connection refuse. Same after deleate this option. I must try to get my old status back and after changing back i would look to the answer from user1881277

Comment: connection refuse can happen if mysql has too many sleep connections or too many connections to be closed at TCP level. These two type can be verified by the above steps given in the comment. net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout is specifies the number of seconds that the tcp connection should wait until it receives fin request (request to close the connection). You can adjust this value according to your application queries. If the issue is at TCP level please add net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1 too and see.

Comment: okay, i have add net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1 to /etc/sysctl.conf. This looks better, SSH work again. But the webserver(Lighttpd) make the same problems. He refuse just all websites(html and php files)

Comment: I think i have found the origin problem: 
root@Bone:~ php5 -v
php5: /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.20: version `libmysqlclient_20.0' not found (required by php5)